# Why is the radical of a Clifford algebra generated by the kernel of the associated symmetric form?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, clifford-algebras

I was recently reading through Jacobson's Basic Algebra. I got to the section on Clifford algebras, and have the following question.

Let $Cl_\omega$ be the [Clifford algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra) with bilinear symmetric form $\omega$ on a vector space $V$.

I hear that the Jacobson radical $\text{rad}(Cl_\omega)$ is generated by $\ker\omega$, but it's not immediately clear to my why it is. How can one see this? Thanks.

Comment: Darn, is nobody interested in my question? :( Is there a way to make it better?

Comment: Personally I do not know what you mean by "radical." Do you mean the Jacobson radical?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I do, I will add that, thanks.

Comment: This question has already been asked (and answered!) in this site. Search for it.

Comment: Hopefully you found it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131953/quotient-of-a-clifford-algebra-by-its-radical-is-a-clifford-algebra

Comment: Thanks @rschwieb. I did find it, but I guess this is good for any who sees this question in the future.