# Unique irreducible complex representation of Clifford algebra implies isomorphism with matrix algebra

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, clifford-algebras, irreducible-representation

> Consider the Clifford algebra $\mathrm{Cl}(n)$ over Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the standard inner product).

> Now, in the case that $n$ is even, it is known (cf. [1]), then $\mathrm{Cl}(n)$ has a **unique irreducible** complex representation $\Delta$ (unique up to equivalence). Now, in [2], it is claimed (without proof) that this very fact implies that $$\mathrm{Cl}(n) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \simeq \mathrm{End}(\Delta), $$ and this is an isomorphism of algebras.

However, I cannot do find a proof or formulate a proof myself. I have a slight feeling that this might be either a trivial result, or a very well-known result, but I do not where to find a proof.

Thank you in advance.

[1] *Spin Geometry*, H. Blaine Lawson and Marie-Louise Michelsohn

[2] *Elliptic operators, Topology, and Asymptotic methods*, John Roe

Comment: If a finite-dimensional algebra $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is *semisimple*, then the standard structure theory of finite-dimensional algebras tells you that $A \cong \bigoplus_i \operatorname{End}_\mathbb{C}(V_i)$, where the sum is over isomorphism classes of irreps of $A$. This gives the result, provided that you know that $Cl(n)$ is semisimple, as in it has zero radical. Assumedly you can check that the radical of $Cl(n)$ is zero, so the algebra is semisimple.

Comment: @Joppy I see; but how can I compute the (Jacobson) radical of the Clifford algebra? I have seen it claimed (for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131953/quotient-of-a-clifford-algebra-by-its-radical-is-a-clifford-algebra ) that the radical of the Clifford algebra is the ideal generated by the kernel of the corresponding bilinear form, but I do not know how to prove this.